# Can Kubernetes handle thousands of services?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to create a cluster to deploy thousands of apps, which are independent from each other. Each app is composed by 4-5 pods that need to talk to each other. Each of those pods need to scale and can be anywhere in the cluster, so I have to use services so they can communicate.

Due to the way Kubernetes manages services, where it creates an environment variable for each service and updates a local proxy on each node, I was wondering if that will scale well even if I have thousands of services, or maybe hundreds of thousands of services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question. I have filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/3345.

We've just started packaging up SkyDNS with our clusters; DNS for service discovery may meet your needs better than env variables.